# Removing space between two html elements: textbox and glyphicon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to dynmaically add rows in an html form. However, I have small issue: 
My form is:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "mydiv" class="controls  multi-field-wrapper row">
        <div class="multi-fields">
            <div class="multi-field col-md-11 col-lg-11">
                <input type="text" name="how_many[]" placeholder="How many?" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
                <input type="text" name="where_when[]" placeholder="When and Where?" class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 " >
            </div>
        <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-lg-1" style='margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; float: left;'>
            <span class="add-field glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
        </a>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

and my jquery script is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    var remove = '<a href="#" style="padding-left:20px" class ="remove-field "><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></a>';

    $(".add-field", $(this)).on('click', function(e)  {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).append(remove).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
    });
    $('.multi-field ', $wrapper).on('click', '.remove-field' ,function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
    });
});
});
```

However the problem is that the plus glyphicon is far from textbox while minus glyphicon is nearer which is what is required, as in the image. How can I also move the plus glyphicon in similar distance to the minus glyphicon from the textbox.

[image]

This should be extremely but I am a newbee in the area, could you identify the problem and suggest the solution. Thanks!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?  i think this will be css isseu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/gurn5zh9/

First put your `a tag` that `add new field` into your `main div`

```
<div id = "mydiv" class="controls  multi-field-wrapper row">
  <div class="multi-fields">
    <div class="multi-field col-md-11 col-lg-11">
      <input type="text" name="how_many[]" placeholder="How many?" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
      <input type="text" name="where_when[]" placeholder="When and Where?" class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 " >
    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 addField" style='padding-left:20px'>
      <span class="add-field glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  </div>
```

then in your script remove it from the clone :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    var remove = '<a href="#" style="padding-left:20px" class ="remove-field "><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></a>';

    $(".add-field", $(this)).on('click', function(e)  {
        e.preventDefault();
        $ccc = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).append(remove).appendTo($wrapper);
        $ccc.find('.addField').remove();
        $ccc.find('input').val('').focus();
    });
    $('.multi-field ', $wrapper).on('click', '.remove-field' ,function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

there is not any problem in your jQuery code. but problem is in your HTML Code.
here

**you are not closing html tags properly**
  properly use your classes in HTML and as well as in js file where you creating your HTML element dynamically & using same css style for both if you want same functionality.

don't change your script & try this

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<!-- Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
<div id = "mydiv" class="controls  multi-field-wrapper row">
    <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field col-md-11 col-lg-11">
            <input type="text" name="how_many[]" placeholder="How many?" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
            <input type="text" name="where_when[]" placeholder="When and Where?" class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 " >
            <a href="#" style="padding-left:20px;" class="add-field">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>      
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Output will be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fact is, your "a" tag for the "plusicon" is out of div "multi-fields". When you create a new row, you append "minusicon" in the "multi-fields" div. That's why it's not the same position between both.

Bad things which can fix it :

```
<a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-lg-1" style='margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; float: left; margin-left: -88px;'>
```

I'm looking for a better way using jquery, update when i found it.

UPDATE :

First, put your a tag of plusicon into multi-field div

```
    <div class="multi-field col-md-11 col-lg-11">
        <input type="text" name="how_many[]" placeholder="How many?" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
        <input type="text" name="where_when[]" placeholder="When and Where?" class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 " >
         <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-lg-1" style='mpadding-left:20px '>
            <span class="add-field glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Then, when you want to clone it, remove from the clone the a tag.

```
   $(".add-field", $(this)).on('click', function(e)  {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newclone =  $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true);
        newclone.find("a").remove();
        newclone.append(remove).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip: You forgot to close your `<div class="multi-fields">` :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<input type="text" name="how_many[]" placeholder="How many?" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
<input type="text" name="where_when[]" placeholder="When and Where?" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 " >
```